# Pandas: Histogram Plotting

Tags: python, pandas, plot, visualization

I have a dataframe with dates (datetime) in python. How can I plot a histogram with 30 min bins from the occurrences using this dataframe?

```
             starttime
1 2016-09-11 00:24:24
2 2016-08-28 00:24:24
3 2016-07-31 05:48:31
4 2016-09-11 00:23:14
5 2016-08-21 00:55:23
6 2016-08-21 01:17:31
       .............
989872 2016-10-29 17:31:33
989877 2016-10-02 10:00:35
989878 2016-10-29 16:42:41
989888 2016-10-09 07:43:27
989889 2016-10-09 07:42:59
989890 2016-11-05 14:30:59
```

I have tried looking at examples from [Plotting series histogram in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511357/plotting-series-histogram-in-pandas) and [A per-hour histogram of datetime using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814606/a-per-hour-histogram-of-datetime-using-pandas). But they seem to be using a bar plot which is not what I need. I have attempted to create the histogram using `temp.groupby([temp["starttime"].dt.hour, temp["starttime"].dt.minute]).count().plot(kind="hist")` giving me the results as shown below

[image]

If possible I would like the X axis to display the time(e.g 07:30:00)

Comment: Your histogram looks like a bar plot to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `bar` plot and for axis with times simpliest is convert `datetime`s to `string`s by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
temp = temp.resample('30T', on='starttime').count()
ax = temp.groupby(temp.index.strftime('%H:%M')).sum().plot(kind="bar")

#for nicer bar some ticklabels are hidden
spacing = 2
visible = ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::spacing]
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    if label not in visible:
        label.set_visible(False)
```